# Error expected unqualified-id before 'if' compilando aplicación para ESP32

Tags: arduino, esp32

Me sale este error al intentar hacer un programa en ESP32 para controlar un servo motor:

> ```
> SerialToSerialBT:33:2: error: expected unqualified-id before 'if'
>   if (letra == 0) {
>   ^
> exit status 1
> expected unqualified-id before 'if'
> ```

Por el momento solo estoy intentando que si lo que hay en el puerto serie monitor es 0 (lo mando de una aplicación conectada al ESP32) mande una señal al servo para que se ponga a 0 grados.

Aquí está el código:

```
Servo motor;

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

#define servoPin 2

char letra;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialBT.begin("Knee Drive"); //Bluetooth device name
  Serial.println("The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth!");
  motor.attach(servoPin);
}


void loop() {

  if(SerialBT.available() > 0)
    letra = SerialBT.read();
    Serial.print(letra);
}

  if (letra == 0) {
  Serial.print("0 Grados");

}
```

Comment: El mensaje de error te está diciendo que se ha encontrado un `if` fuera de un bloque permitido (por ejemplo, dentro de una función). Deberías comprobar los bloques `{}`, en particular la apertura del corchete del bloque `if(SerialBT.available() > 0)` que hace que se cierre prematuramente la definición de la función `loop`, lo que hace que el siguiente `if` esté fuera de la función y, por lo tanto, fuera de un lugar permitido.

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje de error te está diciendo que se ha encontrado un `if` fuera de un bloque permitido (por ejemplo, dentro de una función).

Esto es debido a que en la función `loop()` te faltan dos corchetes:

```
void loop() {

  if (SerialBT.available() > 0) { // Aquí uno
    letra = SerialBT.read();
    Serial.print(letra);
  }

  if (letra == 0) {
     Serial.print("0 Grados");
  } // Aquí otro
}
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, tienes mi +1. Me he tomado la libertad de agregar a tu respuesta el motivo del mensaje de error y corregir el sangrado del código.